# Getting Value of dynamic form fields using Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a form dynamically created using Jquery and i am trying to validate the form but every time i try to get the input field value it says "undefined" , My code to get value

```
var username = $('#username').val();
       console.log(username);
```

Edited : Below function will add the form field to the div.modal

```
    function AddUserDialog(){
      var temp = '<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />';
       $('.modal').html(temp);
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the form that is dynamically created

Comment: We are going to need more information. Your question is the equivalent of "I'm trying to drive my car, but every time I try to drive it, it has problems."  How is the form being created? Have you made sure it's in the DOM when you're searching for it with jQuery? Have you made sure its id is properly 'username'... so on.

Comment: @corbin :- yes form is in the dom and id is also correct..

Comment: does that input element gets appended to DOM. Check it in firebug or chrome dev tools.

Comment: The code to pull the username value must be getting run before the code that is inserting the element into the DOM then. What triggers the validation event?

Comment: if html is getting added in DOM, at what point are you grabbing the username value? Is it on some event like click? If you are using version less than 1.7, then use live, or use 'on'

Comment: love it when questions asked have to be longer than the oriignal "question"

Comment: @charlietfl: couldn't agree more

Comment: Crab? You mean crap? I'm trying to figure out your question.  No offense, but your original question was very bad. Anyway, looks like you've now gotten your answer, so whatever works I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#form_id").live('submit',function(){
    if($(this).find('#username').val()==''){
        alert('username cant left empty!!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Because the form is created by jquery your script can't find it in document and will return undefined..
For such cases we have 3 functions we can use..**live,delegate and on**..

Read following links for more details..

[Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: live and delegate are deprecated, just for what it may be worth.